# Large amount of Memory needed with VB.NET but not with VBA

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba

I'm having issues with my application regarding memory usage and I can't seem to find the solution.
I started with a VBA macro which copies data from one sheet to another in different workbooks. For multiple reasons, I have copied the code in a VB.NET application.

The VBA code is able to copy thousands of cells with data at once, using this line:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(j - 1, 1), ws.Cells(j + rij.Rows.Count - 2, 1)).EntireRow.Formula = rij.Formula
```

In this case, the variable "rij" is a range.

In my VB.NET application, I use exactly the same line of code. In some cases, it needs 1.5GB of memory. When using 32 bits Excel, this often causes a System.outofmemoryexception error.

Does any of you know why VB.NET needs to use a lot of memory, while VBA doesn't? And more important, is there a way to use VB.NET without the large amount of memory?

I really hope you can help me!

Comment: It is easy to write VB.NET code that manipulates large amounts of Excel data but never puts enough pressure on the GC heap to cause the garbage collector to run.  Diagnose by using the .NET performance counters in perfmon.exe.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/performance-counters#memory  Fix by calling GC.Collect() after moving enough data around.  Or writing the code you intended to write.

Comment: You are loading the VB.NET stack on top of Excel and VBA. It would naturally use more resources.

Comment: The memory usage goes from 250MB to 1.6GB in a single line of code. In the diagnostics tool I can see that the GC is activated sometimes. Also, after the single line, the memory immediately goes back to 250MB. I can imagine that VB.NET requires more resources, but I find it strange that with VBA the memory hardly moves. Also it takes about 20 seconds to copy the data when using VB.NET, but it takes 1 second to do exactly the same manually or with VBA.

Comment: If I counted correctly, that single line creates 5 Range references and one String.   Those references are highly unlikely to account for memory consumption you claim is caused on statement execution.    Or is that memory consumption of that statement being executed an unspecified number of times in a loop.  It is also strange that you are assigning a formula to every column in a worksheet row.